# Scale fxg graphic

Tags: actionscript-3

i try to scale *.fxg graphic in as3 project, but problem is that visually image is scaled, but width property stays same as original. If i change width property image is resized good visually and also property is correct. With *.svg for instance there is no problem with that.

```
var logo:Sprite = new Logo() //Logo.fxg - width 400px
logo.scaleX = .5
trace(logo.width) //400
logo.width = 200
trace(logo.width) //200
```

Comment: I think your problem is linked to mine that I post here: [coordinates-dont-change-dragging-scaled-fxg-graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054891/coordinates-dont-change-dragging-scaled-fxg-graphics)

Comment: Look answers in AntionioG question.

Comment: Please correct your question so you ask about something! Now you just described how Flash Player work and should work!